--shm_size change for Docker in Nextflow pipeline: containerOptions not seeming to work
I am trying to increase the shared memory size for the Docker image being used to run a Nextflow pipeline. Per some indications online, I have added the following to my config file:
docker {
    enabled = true
    userEmulation = true 
    containerOptions = '--shm-size=256m'
}

No errors are thrown, and in Nextflow towers it looks like the config was successfully ingested. However, I am still running into issues where I run out of shared memory when training a pytorch model. To check whether my shm-size change was actually doing anything, I added a command to check what the size is within the nextflow process script section: df -h /dev/shm, and it looks like the shm was in fact not updated -- it still is the default 64M which apparently is normal for Docker.
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm

I've been trying different approaches to this for hours and it's pretty frustrating -- is this the right way to do this? I also tried setting the directive directly within the process instead of at the top level config, and this also did not work. Is there a workaround or another way to increase the shm size? It's preventing me from running pytorch training using multiple workers, which means my trainings are super slow.
Thanks.

Try instead using docker.runOptions. For example with the following in your nextflow.config:
docker {

    enabled = true
    runOptions = '--shm-size=256m'
}

And the following in your main.nf:
process test_proc {

    debug true

    container 'ubuntu:24.04'

    """
    df -h /dev/shm
    """
}

workflow {

    test_proc()
}

Results:
$ nextflow run main.nf 

 N E X T F L O W   ~  version 24.04.3

Launching `main.nf` [stupefied_shannon] DSL2 - revision: 306a1b97c1

executor >  local (1)
[ef/0639d1] process > test_proc [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
shm             256M     0  256M   0% /dev/shm



I'll try that out, thanks!

Unfortunately it did not work:
outputting shm size
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm

Although the Resolved configuration detected the setting:
Resolved configuration
docker {
enabled = true
userEmulation = true
runOptions = '--shm-size=256m'
}

@ekofman I couldn't find any documentation for your userEmulation option in the docker scope. It might be causing problems. Can you try removing it?

You're right, it appears it was removed somewhat recently: https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/pull/4596

removing it didn't help though  :/

@ekofman Were you able to get my minimal example working? I'm wondering if the problem is specific to your environment or container image.
